# Does qsub pass command line arguments to my script?

Tags: pbs, qsub, torque

When I submit a job using

```
qsub script.sh
```

is `$@` setted to some value inside `script.sh`? That is, are there any command line arguments passed to `script.sh`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can pass arguments to the job script using the -F option of qsub:

```
qsub script.sh -F "args to script"
```

or inside script.sh:

```
#PBS -F arguments
```

This is documented [here.](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/suite/8-0/basic/help.htm#topics/torque/commands/qsub.htm#-f)

Comment: is there an example on how to use this argument inside the script, I need to create a folder with the -F argument name.

Comment: No option `-F` with PBSPro_13.1.2.163512.

Comment: I gave a torque-specific answer because this question has a Torque label, and because I don't know much about PBSPro.

Answer (score 11):

On my platform the `-F` is not available. As a substitute `-v` helped:

```
qsub -v "var=value" script.csh
```

And then use the variable `var` in your script.
See also the [documentation](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/suite/8-0/basic/help.htm#topics/torque/commands/qsub.htm#-v).

Answer (score 0):

No. Just tried to submit a script with arguments before I answered and qsub won't accept it.

This won't be as convenient as putting arguments on the command line but you could possibly set some environment variables which you can have Torque export to the job with -v [var name} or -V.